# E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser, mozilla, linux-mint

I want to install firefox in linuxmint

I run this command:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

It shows error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
linux-headers-5.4.0-65 linux-headers-5.4.0-65-generic linux-image-5.4.0-65-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-65-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-65-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
xul-ext-ubufox
Suggested packages:
fonts-lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
firefox xul-ext-ubufox
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 56.5 MB/56.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 223 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 https://mintmirror.netfirst.in ulyssa/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 86.0.1+linuxmint1+ulyssa [56.5 MB]
Err:1 https://mintmirror.netfirst.in ulyssa/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 86.0.1+linuxmint1+ulyssa
Hash Sum mismatch
Hashes of expected file:

- SHA256:3dea5921498fda8bcf3ce9b661d597aeab1e38f164825414d38b3ff486cf6ab8
- SHA1:f0456c06b42f5ce025d33ca92cc50637922bba7c [weak]
- MD5Sum:b32026167d2427b9a5e6b8915f46d10f [weak]
- Filesize:56464752 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
- SHA256:76b4d52415582d9491423724487a3846b3def8e561ed522122e78c1f2db0812f
- SHA1:396fef8f0c5a5139f0f417098c51bd63951c17a2 [weak]
- MD5Sum:f84d1dc6e70e0251b33848e7bb0565bc [weak]
- Filesize:56464752 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Mon, 15 Mar 2021 13:31:04 +0000
  Fetched 56.5 MB in 9s (6,636 kB/s)
  E: Failed to fetch https://mintmirror.netfirst.in/pool/upstream/f/firefox/firefox_86.0.1+linuxmint1+ulyssa_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
  - SHA256:3dea5921498fda8bcf3ce9b661d597aeab1e38f164825414d38b3ff486cf6ab8
  - SHA1:f0456c06b42f5ce025d33ca92cc50637922bba7c [weak]
  - MD5Sum:b32026167d2427b9a5e6b8915f46d10f [weak]
  - Filesize:56464752 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
  - SHA256:76b4d52415582d9491423724487a3846b3def8e561ed522122e78c1f2db0812f
  - SHA1:396fef8f0c5a5139f0f417098c51bd63951c17a2 [weak]
  - MD5Sum:f84d1dc6e70e0251b33848e7bb0565bc [weak]
  - Filesize:56464752 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Mon, 15 Mar 2021 13:31:04 +0000
  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Anything helpful information would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you didn't closed that port properly and the connection/port is still running in the background. (Maybe you exited by pressing **ctrl+z** instead of **ctrl+c**)
You can use this to kill that process:

```
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

Note: 8000 is the port number.

Comment: sudo fuser -k 8000 =>
still not working for me

Comment: @TechCure please try `sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp`
 Let me know if that works.

Comment: yes => sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp is workable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be some other program using the port `8000`.

You could try using

```sh
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8000
```

to see what process is using port `8000`.